# Problem in installing Python 3.3 in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: installation, python

Initially I installed Python 3.3 from source, but then I removed and deleted the directory `/usr/lib/python3.3`.

When I am installing it using aptitude, I am getting this error.

```
Unpacking python3.3 (from .../python3.3_3.3.1-1ubuntu5_i386.deb) ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Setting up python3.3 (3.3.1-1ubuntu5) ...
python3.3: can't open file '/usr/lib/python3.3/py_compile.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing python3.3 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3.3
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
A package failed to install.  Trying to recover:
Setting up python3.3 (3.3.1-1ubuntu5) ...
python3.3: can't open file '/usr/lib/python3.3/py_compile.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing python3.3 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
```

Any idea how to rectify the error?

Answer (score 4):

You've destroyed the `libpython3.3-minimal` package in that removal. Reinstall it, than try installing `python3.3` again. If you have other packages installed that depend on `libpython3.3-minimal`, they may need to be reinstalled too.

<sub>Note: For next time, manually installed software should go in `/usr/local` or `/opt`, never to `/usr` directly. That avoids conflict between manually installed files and packages, because all packages are installed to `/usr`.</sub>

Comment: +1. Never touch system files in `/usr` directly!

Comment: While the diagnosis is not false, the recommend action does not address the OP's problem. He actually tries to install python3.3 again, but he can't.

Comment: @JoBo: The suggestion says "Reinstall libpython3.3-minimal". That solves the current OP's problem. I added the paragraph about where manual installations should go based on qertvdijk's comment.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, you say "Reinstall _it_", I just read "try installing python 3.3 again". :) ...but the OP probably broke more than just libpython3.3-minimal. It is just the package whose file happens to trigger the error message while installing python3.3. We can't assume that other packages are not affected.

Comment: @JoBo: well, he does not have python3.3 installed, so he can't have anything that depends on it installed either.

Comment: He implied so, but how did apt miss a Pre-Depends then? Better safe than sorry. In the end the unexperienced user would run into yet another error message.

Comment: s/Pre-Depends/Depends/

Comment: @JoBo: Something that depends on libpython3.3-minimal had to be installed. And you are right, it might need to be reinstalled too.

Answer (score 1):

To install python version 3.3.2 here are the steps I followed and it worked

```
wget http://python.org/ftp/python/3.3.2/Python-3.3.2.tar.bz2

tar -xvjf ./Python-3.3.2.tar.bz2

cd ./Python-3.3.2

./configure --prefix=/opt/python3.3

make && make install

mkdir ~/bin

ln -s /opt/python3.3/bin/python ~/bin/py

echo 'alias py="/opt/python3.3/bin/python3"' >> .bashrc
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have 'destroyed' parts of you Python install---as Jan Hudec points out---installing python3.3 fails because `dpkg` thinks other packages are still there. Check for the packages that were affected by your action:

```
# dpkg -S /usr/lib/python3.3/
python3-gdbm:i386, python3.3, libpython3.3-minimal:i386, libpython3.3-stdlib:i386, libpython3.3:i386: /usr/lib/python3.3
```

And reinstall explicitly all packages that provides files under that directory. This will ensure that the file `/usr/lib/python3.3/py_compile.py` and others that are `pre-depends` will be there at the right time during install *and* that any files that are affected by your action get repaired.

Note: Your output from above command may differ, adjust the following accordingly.

```
# aptitude reinstall python3-gdbm python3.3 libpython3.3-minimal libpython3.3-stdlib libpython3.3
```