# Python : Need help in installing it in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: python

Initially i installed python3.3 from source but then i removed and deleted the directory `/usr/lib/python3.3`. When I am installing using aptitude I am getting this error:

```
Unpacking python3.3 (from .../python3.3_3.3.1-1ubuntu5_i386.deb) ... 
Processing triggers for man-db ... 
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ... 
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index... 
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ... 
Setting up python3.3 (3.3.1-1ubuntu5) ... 
python3.3: can't open file '/usr/lib/python3.3/py_compile.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory dpkg: error processing python3.3 (--configure): subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2 Errors were encountered while processing: python3.3 E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) A package failed to install. Trying to recover: Setting up python3.3 (3.3.1-1ubuntu5) ... 
python3.3: can't open file '/usr/lib/python3.3/py_compile.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory dpkg: error processing python3.3 (--configure): subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2 Errors were encountered while processing:
```

Comment: Do you specifically want Python3.3?

Comment: See this question: [How to install Python 3.3?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/244544/how-to-install-python-3-3)

Comment: Dup: http://askubuntu.com/questions/337409/problem-in-installing-python3-3-in-ubantu-12-04